# Efficient way to create a class from a datagridview data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there an alternative to load data from a datagridview into a class than to iterate through the datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable myList = myDataGrid.ItemsSource;
```